# ASP.Net conditional databinding

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<% if(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("NbrOrders"))>=Config.MAX_ENQUIRY_SALES) {  %>
...  

<% } else { %>
...                                        

<% } %>
```

Gives me a InvalidOperationException? How do I write conditional html generation in ASP?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use an inline statement as John_ states, or, create a function in your code behind that performs the logic required.

```
protected string MyFunction(int nbrOrders)
{
    if(nbrOrders>=Config.MAX_ENQUIRY_SALES)
    {
        return "TrueResult";
    }
    else
    {
        return "FalseResult";
    }
}
```

Then use this as follows

```
<%# MyFunction(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("NbrOrders"))) %>
```

EDIT: I've just read a comment on another post that states you want to show different HTML depending on this result. In that case, you can try using the Visible flag of a placeholder containing your code. Such as:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder id="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" visible='<%# (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("NbrOrders"))>=Config.MAX_ENQUIRY_SALES)%>'>
    <div>My True Html Here</div>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
<asp:PlaceHolder id="PlaceHolder2" runat="server" visible='<%# !(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("NbrOrders"))>=Config.MAX_ENQUIRY_SALES)%>'>
    <div>My FalseHtml Here</div>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure you can add brackets for the conditional binding, the only way I know of doing it is with an inline statement like so:

```
<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("NbrOrders"))>=Config.MAX_ENQUIRY_SALES) ? Eval("IfTrueValue") : Eval("IfFalseValue") %>
```

Comment: Yes, I suspected this...my problem is that I need to generated a bunch of html in each case... The whole point of ASP sort is lost...

Comment: @Neils Bosma, This would've been my answer, as well.  You would not be able to mix HTML with Eval bindings, but HTML can still be generated in your function and then put into datacolumn you are binding, then called with Eval("YourColumn").

Answer (score 5):

The problem with @Robin Day's answer is that the following code fails if you have databound children that may or may not have data given the current state of whatever you are rendering. Sometimes it's difficult to maneuver around nullable databound code if you have a complex object graph.

For example, consider:

```
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" Visible="<%# VisibleCondition() %>">

        <%# ((string)null).ToString("c") %> //an object that may have null data
                                            //given the visible condition
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
```

If `VisibleCondition()` returns `false`, child controls still get called with `DataBind()` which can result in a `NullReferenceException` in the example above.

---

Here is a better approach, IMHO:

```
public class ConditionalPlaceHolder : PlaceHolder
{
    protected override void DataBindChildren()
    {
        if( this.Visible )
        {
            base.DataBindChildren();
        }
    }
}
```

And used in the following way:

```
<web:ConditionalPlaceHolder runat="server" Visible="<%# VisibleCondition1() %>">
    //whatever databound code
    <%# ((string)notNullGivenVisibleCondition1).ToString() %>
    <p>But could be given visible condition 2</p>
</web:ConditionalPlaceHolder>

<web:ConditionalPlaceHolder runat="server" Visible="<%# VisibleCondition2() %>">
    //whatever databound code
    <%# ((string)notNullGivenVisibleCondition2).ToString() %>
    <p>But could be given visible condition 1</p>
</web:ConditionalPlaceHolder>
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't find something wrong in your sentences but comparative you made between Config.MAX_ENQUIRY_SALES and Convert.ToInt32(Eval("NbrOrders")). Are these operator of the same type? Can you show the type of each one in your web page?

Answer (score -1):

if/else blocks work in ASP .NET as you expect them to. The following works just fine.

```
<% if(DateTime.Now.Second % 2 == 0) {  %>
<div>Even</div>
<% } else { %>
<div>Odd</div>
<% } %>
```

Perhaps the conditional logic in your example is throwing an exception?

Comment: I think its the Eval that causes the problem. You cant mix conditional logic within the databinding.