# Populating ListView from ObjectDataSource and displaying "N/A" for indeterminate values

Tags: asp.net, listview, objectdatasource

In an ASP.NET ListView control, populated from an ObjectDataSource, how would I show "N/A" for indeterminate values?

[image]

For example, I have a column that shows the average score across play sessions.  There will be some players who have registered but haven't yet played any games yet, so they'd have no meaningful average score.  Rather than showing an average score of 0 (and a grade of "F"), I'd rather show N/A.

I'm using a data transfer object to represent each player.  One approach I tried was to represent the Average Score as a string so that it could sometimes be "N/A", but this seems kinda lame lose the numeric value.  Another idea I had was to have both an AverageScore and AverageScoreDisplayString so that the display string could be set to "N/A" as needed. But this would require the display string field for all columns that might need to show "N/A".

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could wrap a condition around the Eval in the markup?

is this any help [ASP.Net conditional databinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653486/asp-net-conditional-databinding) ?