# How can I use conditional statements during data binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

```
 <div class="oldPrice" <%#if(Eval("OldPrice") == Eval("Price") ){ %> style="display:none" <%}%> >
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653486/asp-net-conditional-databinding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 <div class="oldPrice" <%#(Eval("OldPrice") == Eval("Price")? "style='display:none'":String.Empty) %>>
```