# How to add if-else statement to change BoundFields of GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to do something like the code below:

```
<%= if(ddlChoice.SelectedItem.Value ==1) { %>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name">
      <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" /></asp:BoundField>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName"  HeaderText="Last Name">
      <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" /></asp:BoundField>
<%= } else {  %>>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name">
      <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" /></asp:BoundField>
<%= } %>
```

I have a `GridView`, now I want to add if-else condition to change available `BoundField`s according to selected item in `DropDownList`... Please Guide me !!!

Comment: is it working?what error are you getting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.Net conditional databinding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653486/asp-net-conditional-databinding)

Answer (score 0):

In short: You cannot place your `if` statement between `BoundField`s as you are trying to do.

As an alternative solution, you could change the `Visible` property of each `BoundField` either from code behind or by setting a boolean value to that attribute in your .aspx file.

Another alternative solution is to have more than one `GridView` and change their visibility upon user selection.